# Space between columns in amCharts4

Tags: reactjs, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

I am using amCharts4 wth React and I want to add some space between the column as mentioned in the image. How can I achieve this? Basically the space is indicating as a separator between x-axis items. The items on the left of the space represent different category and same goes for the right side.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this chart will help you. You have 3 variables, so better look for 3 dimensional charts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Well you could a column data with value 0 and making sure that label is hidden.
   Inject object similar to following in separation.

   const placeholder = {
   label: 'placeholder',
   key: 'placeholder',
   value: 0,
   tooltip: ''
   };

OR

2. Add padding to columns that stand at the edge of the seperation.
   like

   seriesObj.columns.template.column.paddingLeft = SOME_VALUE